# How should I process XML/JSON REST Requests using Zend Framework minimizing validation logic

Tags: php, zend-framework

I writing a small restful web service using Zend_Framework. I want to support the following;

1. JSON Requests
2. XML Requests
3. Normal HTML Post requests

Context switching is completed via the context switch helper, so no problems there.

However, rather than writing the logic to validate and filter the input of each request type I was wondering if I should do one of the following;

1. Convert JSON/HTTP For Post request to XML and validate against XSD and Zend_Validate*
2. Convert XML/HTTP Form POST Request to JSON using Zend_Json and validate the decoded json using and Zend_Validate*

My question is, what is the best method I can implement that a) allows me to support multiple request types but b) means I don end up writing logic for each different request type to validate?

I find the XML method one that I am leaning too, but would like to know how everyone else(tm) accomplishes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it makes sense in your situation or not, but if you are going to accept different types of input for the same services, you could create a Model for each service method you have, populate the model using each either the JSON, XML, or HTTP input and then validate the data that is stored in the model.

Matthew Weier O'Phinney has a good post on [Using Zend_Form in Your Models](http://mwop.net/blog/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models) that you could use to validate the data as you populate the model.  You could adapt the idea to suit your needs better.

But it seems to me, if you use each input format to populate a common object with the expected data, you could then filter and validate it only once.

Comment: Great idea, here's how I implemented it;

1. Create a validation factory class

2. Add a new private method called validate to Application_Model_Mapper_Foo

3. Updated Application_Model_Mapper_Foo->save($object} to first call $this->validate($object}

4. Validate method, calls factory, instantiates Zend_Validate_??

5. $id->isValid($object->getId()) ? null : throwException(new Exception($id->getMessages()));